# Unexpected behavior of each

Tags: perl

```
%h = (a => 1, b => 2);

keys %h;
while(my($k, $v) = each %h)
{
  $h{uc $k} = $h{$k} * 2; # BAD IDEA!
}
```

The output is :

```
(a => 1, A => 2, b => 2, B => 8)
```

instead of

```
(a => 1, A => 2, b => 2, B => 4)
```

Why?

Comment: Usually, "unexpected" means "I didn't read the docs". When something doesn't work the way you expect, read the docs. You don't have to guess. :)

Answer (score 7):

From [perldoc -f each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)

> If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it,
>   entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that. Exception: It
>   is always safe to delete the item most recently returned by `each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `each` doesn't let you modify items in place like a `for` loop does.  `each` just returns the next key and value for the hash.  You are creating new values in the hash when you say  `$h{uc $k} = $h{$k} * 2;`.  To get the behavior you desire, I would probably say

```
for my $k (keys %h) {
    $h{uc $k} = $h{$k};
    delete $h{$k};
}
```

If the hash is huge and you are worried about storing all of the keys in memory (which is the main use of `each`), then you would be better off saying:

```
my %new_hash;
while (my ($k, $v) = each %h) {
    $new_hash{uc $k} = $v;
    delete $h{$k};
}
```

and then using `%new_hash` instead of `%h`.

As to why some keys get processed more than once, and other don't, first we must look to [the documentation for `each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

> If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that.

That is fine, it tells us what to expect, but not why.  To see why we must create a model of what is happening.  When you assign a value to a hash, the key is turned into a number by a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  This number is then used to index into an array (at the C level, not the Perl level).   For our purposes we can get away with a very simplistic model:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash_function = (
        a => 2,
        b => 1,
        A => 0,
        B => 3
);

my @hash_table;

{
    my $position = 0;
    sub my_each {
        #return nothing if there is nothing
        return unless @hash_table;

        #get the key and value from the next positon in the
        #hash table, skipping empty positions
        until (defined $hash_table[$position]) {
            $position++;
            #return nothing if there is nothing left in the array
            return if $position > $#hash_table;
        }
        my ($k, $v) = %{$hash_table[$position]};

        #set up for the next call
        $position++;

        #if in list context, return both key an value
        #if in scalar context, return the key
        return wantarray ? ($k, $v) : $k;
    }
}


$hash_table[$hash_function{a}] = { a => 1 }; # $h{a} = 1;
$hash_table[$hash_function{b}] = { b => 2 }; # $h{b} = 2;

while (my ($k, $v) = my_each) {
    # $h{$k} = $v * 2;
    $hash_table[$hash_function{uc $k}] = { uc $k => $v * 2 };
}

print Dumper \@hash_table;
```

For this example, we can see that when the key `"A"` gets added to the hash table, it is put before the other keys, so it doesn't get processed a second time, but the key `"B"` **does** get placed after the other keys, so it the `my_each` function sees it on the first pass (as the item following the key `"a"`).

Comment: It seems `B` is calculated twice,why?

Comment: Because changing the entries potentially changes the order that they are stored it, thereby invalidating the data that the 'each' iterator is using.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is changing `%h` on the fly, so it interprets twice the value of `b` (first `b`, then `B`). The semantics of `each` work by removing a pair from the hash, and then returning it, but you're adding it afterwards within the loop, so it may get processed later. You should get the keys first, and then loop that to get the values. For example:

```
my @keys = keys %h;
foreach (@keys)
{
 $h{uc $_} = $h{$_} * 2;
 delete $h{$_};
}
```

As Chas. Owens above pointed, as `each` removes the element, you have to remove them too.

Another cute thing you can do is use map to create a new hash:

```
my %result  = map {uc $_ => $h{$_} * 2} (keys %h);
```

and then use the hash `%result`.

Comment: why `a` is not interpreted twice?

Comment: In the first case, because the keys are computed first. In the second case, because `map` is creating a *new* hash.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
%h = (a => 1, b => 2);
keys %h;
for my $k (keys %h ) {
    $h{uc $k} = $h{$k} * 2;
}
while ( ($k,$v) = each %h ) {
    print "$k => $v\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A => 2
a => 1
b => 2
B => 4
```

Comment: This is due to the nature of the hash function used.  Different versions of Perl have slightly different hash functions and/or seeds (Perl 5.8.0 actually guaranteed random ordering every time you ran the program).  Perl guarantees that order of the keys will only remain the same so long as you do not add or remove a key.  This is why the documentation for `each` says "If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that."

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `warn $k;` to your loop might make things a bit more clear - I get the same result as you do, and it is because the keys it ends up using are 'a', 'b' and then 'B', so:

```
#round 1 ($k='a'):
$h{uc 'a'} = 1 * 2;
# $h{A} = 2;

#round 2: ($k='b'):
$h{uc 'b'} = 2 * 2;
# $h{B} = 4;

#round 3: ($k='B'):
$h{uc 'B'} = 4 * 2;
# $h{B} = 8;
```

Why is it running the loop with the key 'B' but not 'A'? This is because the `each` call is being run every time it goes through the loop (so it is working with the new version of the hash), but it is remembering the last value it was working with, so in this case, when 'A' is added to the hash, it is assigned a position before 'a', so it never gets seen.